# How to list duplicates based on different criteria's T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm looking for someone to help me with a very specific task I have.

I'm analysing data from computer hard drives and need to be able to list folders which are duplicated after being extracted from .zip files. Here is an example of the data I am working with:

| ItemName | Extension | ItemType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyZipFolder.zip | .zip | File |
| MyZipFolder | null | Folder |
| PersonalDocuments.zip | .zip | File |
| PersonalDocuments | null | Folder |

As you can see the extension '.zip' is included in the 'ItemName' and 'Extension' column. When extracted from a .zip file, it becomes a folder. I need a way of listing either the .zip file or the folder which it becomes after extraction (either will do, it just needs to be listed with the knowledge that it is a duplicate).

The caveat to this is that my data consists of plenty other folders and files with different extensions e.g. '.docx', '.msg' so the query needs to discount these.

I hope this makes sense - thanks!

**Expected output might look something like this:**

| ItemName | Extension | ItemType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyZipFolder | null | Folder |
| PersonalDocuments | null | Folder |

So a list of all the folders which I know have a .zip equivalent in the data.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, could you put an example (expected output) based on your sample data?

Comment: well, a folder name can be like 'Myzipfolder.zip` and still be folder , you have to find another way to distinguish them

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @James I've put expected output, I don't know if that helps?

Comment: @eshirvana in the data I have, all .zip files have an 'ItemType' of File

Comment: so if you have that column, then what's the problem ? just `select * from table where extension is null` ???

Comment: @eshirvana There's thousands of folders in my data (just like there is on a laptop/pc). How do I know they all came from extracting a .zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure yet, but do you mean something like this?

```
select *
from your_table y
where ItemType = 'Folder'
  and exists (
    select 1 from your_table yy
    where yy.Extension = '.zip'
      and yy.ItemName = y.ItemName + '.zip'
  )
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for - thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, I am going to change the query in order to make it sargable

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you need :

```
select ItemName 
from tablename
group by replace(ItemName, isnull(Extension,''))
having case count(case when Extension = '.zip' then 1 end) > 1
```